# "Session XXXXXXX does not exists" is shown when executing selenium scripts remotely

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I get the following errors:

```
2012-07-04 15:33:36,582 INFO root:68 - 
at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:57)
at TestRunner.startTests(TestRunner.java:108)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:309)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at Tc.tcCloseSelenium(Tc.java:112)
at Uc.closeSelenium(Uc.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:346)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor85.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Session ID: 7a5fee88-98ec-441b-8412-b9fc9cf73b66
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_01'
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 15:28:49'
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: session 7a5fee88-98ec-441b-8412-b9fc9cf73b66 does not exist
2012-07-04 15:33:36,457 INFO root:58 - Tc.tcCloseSelenium
at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:57)
at TestRunner.startTests(TestRunner.java:108)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:309)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at Tc.tcCloseSelenium(Tc.java:112)
at Uc.closeSelenium(Uc.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:346)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor85.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Session ID: 7a5fee88-98ec-441b-8412-b9fc9cf73b66
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_01'
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 15:28:49'
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: session 7a5fee88-98ec-441b-8412-b9fc9cf73b66 does not exist
```

This happens at the very beginning (most probably the `seleniumDriver.get(ddt.gv.get("app_url"));` command) of the script execution process remotely via some ASP.net webapplication. As a result all the Test&Use cases fail.

The webdriver is internetexplorerdriver:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings" , true);

InternetExplorerDriver seleniumDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
seleniumDriver.get(ddt.gv.get("app_url"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to cleanup your test multiple times?

The thing is..

if you are doing driver.Close() or any type of cleanup multiple times, its gonna erase/close what you want to cleanup then those objects are not found and that is the error you get!

Hope it helps! Let me know!